# Angular Factory return null but shows result in console

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory service and here a method getCount. When I call this method in my controller it's return null but I have tested in my factory service by printing data in the console. It shows data in console but not return any value to my controller.

```
obj.getCount = function(table, field) {
        var query = "select count(" + field + ") as total from " + table + "";
        $db.query(query).then(function(results) {
            console.log(results.rows.item(0).total); // here show data in console
            if (results.rows.item(0).total) {
                return results.rows.item(0).total;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

        });
    }
```

In my controller

```
$scope.totalAccount=DBFactory.getCount('accounts','id');
```

Comment: $db.query(query).then is async function, so You can't use return to get the result, You can use Promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the `$db.query.then` like so:

```
obj.getCount = function(table, field) {
    var query = "select count(" + field + ") as total from " + table + "";
    return $db.query(query).then(function(results) {
        if (results.rows.item(0).total) {
            return results.rows.item(0).total;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Then change your controller code to:

```
DBFactory.getCount('accounts','id').then(function(data) {
    $scope.totalAccount = data;
});
```